# Updating $scope with cordova & angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an App using cordova, ionic and angular. In this function it's supposed to choose a number from the contacts and update an input with it.

This is executed in a ng-click:

```
$scope.buscarContato = function(){
$scope.phone = [];
$scope.phoneId = 0;
$scope.contact = [];
navigator.contacts.pickContact(function (contact){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.contact = contact;
  });
  $scope.selecionarPhone(contact.phoneNumbers); 
},function (err){
   console.log('Error: ' + err);
});
};


$scope.selecionarPhone = function(phoneNumbers){
var phones = [];
var phoneId = [];
if(!phoneNumbers) return;
 for(var i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++){
  phones.push({"text": phoneNumbers[i].value});
  phoneId.push( phoneNumbers[i].id );
}

var options = {
  titleText: "Escolha o número a ser pesquisado",
  buttons: phones,
  cancelText: 'Cancelar',
  cancelOnStateChange: true,
  buttonClicked: function (index) {
    $scope.phone = phones[index].text;
    $scope.phoneId = phoneId[index];
    $scope.contatoExiste = true;
    return true;
  }
};

$ionicActionSheet.show(options);

};
```

In the end, the update of input:

```
$scope.phone = removerMascara(phones[index].text);
```

Input:

```
<input type="tel" placeholder="11999999999" name="phone" data-ng-model="phone" maxlength="15" required>
```

I'm having issues with the input and the scope itself. The execution above occurs normally, but if i try to change the input manually, the input stops updating, even when the search still executes normally.

Does anyone notice what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by change the input manually?

Comment: The phone's keyboard

Comment: Does removerMascara actually return anything?

Comment: Yes. I just replace/remove special characters from the number and return it